# How Receiving WM_Notify in win32 python

Tags: pywin32, win32gui

I want to get notification to my Form or Dialog handle that one of the control(Ex Button) got its state changed by performing some action(Ex Selecting an Item from combobox) in the same Form or Dialog

I have tried to implement on_notify, but for some reason Its not getting called on occurrence of any event change in the form or Dialog

I need to get on_notify method to be called on any kind of style or state changed in my Dialog or form and also find which control sent the notification to the Toplevel dialog

Comment: Button notifications are sent through `WM_COMMAND`

Comment: How about other control like richedit, combobox and some ActiveX controls do they fall in same WM_COMMAND